# How will Windows treat the presence of the "$RECYCLE.BIN" folder on a volume if it's not hidden

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, recycle-bin, hidden-file

So - here's the situation. I've recently been working on a hard drive backup that was copied from a failing drive to a replacement - specialised lab recovery software was used to perform this task. When receiving the replacement drive, I noticed that when connecting it to my Windows-based machine that at the top level folder is a directory named "RECYCLE.BIN". I'm aware that this folder is typically hidden (presumably via the "system" attribute) - it's worth noting at this point that whilst I do have hidden files shown in Windows Explorer (via changing the relevant option from within the Folder Options GUI), I don't have the displaying of hidden operating system files/folders (marked with the "system" attribute) enabled.

So - my question. My presumption is that the presence of this folder is simply due to the fact that whichever recovery tool used on the faling drive simply copied everything that it could find, but didn't mirror the attributes on the folder - so that it's no longer being hidden and not marked as a system folder. In this case, will Windows be happy using this folder to store files deleted from this drive (if they're moved to the Recycle Bin) - or will it create a new, hidden directory for any files/folders deleted in this way?

Answer (score 0):

`RECYCLE.BIN` is not a special folder.
The special folder is named `$Recycle.Bin`.

I assume this is a miscopied `$Recycle.Bin` folder, so has no longer
any special role.